# How to use jmespath operator to match key on non array list

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

I am trying to match certain key from an ansible output/vars, and return the value of another key.

Here is my vars.

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "ansibletower1_422c3aed-780c-8c33-3054-d32e330c9285": {
                "guest.hostName": "ansibletower1.rh.pro",
                "name": "ansibletower1"
            },
            "child domain_422c4cd1-d644-7eeb-df7c-c32a2a05c030": {
                "guest.hostName": null,
                "name": "child domain"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My non-working playbook

```
- hosts: ansibletower1.rh.pro
  tasks:
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ _meta | json_query(querystr) }}"
        vars:
          querystr: "[?hostvars.*.\"guest.hostName\"=='{{inventory_hostname}}'].name"
```

I am trying to follow the method here, https://blog.networktocode.com/post/ansible-filtering-json-query/. However in my scenario is not array, which is different than the example in the link.

My end goal is to match `guest.hostName` with `{{ inventory_hostname }}`,  and return the value of the `name` by  using `- set_fact:` to register it to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try with:

```
tasks:
  - name: Loop over data and continue if string was found.
    debug:
      msg: "{{ _meta | json_query(querystr) }}"
    vars:
      querystr: "hostvars.* | [?\"guest.hostName\"==`{{inventory_hostname}}`].name"
```

when you select all keys with `.*` you get an array back, so it is piped into another query that filters and returns `name`.

Comment: It worked, but need to change `\"{{inventory_hostname}}\"` to ` `{{inventory_hostname}}` `.